# How can you know which index is tracked by a specific index fund?

Tags: united-kingdom, index-fund, vanguard, market-indexes

Looking at this [Vanguard UK index fund](https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/investments/vanguard-uk-short-term-investment-grade-bond-index-fund-accumulation-shares?intcmpgn=fixedincomeuk_ukshortterminvestmentgradebondindexfund_fund_link) (short-term investment grade bonds).

It says:

> The Fund seeks to provide returns consistent with the performance of the index,[...]

How can I know which index the fund is tracking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This kind of information can always be found in the Key Information Document (KID)

The KID states:

> The Fund seeks to provide returns consistent with the performance of the
>   Bloomberg Barclays GBP Non-Government 1-5 Year 200MM Float
>   Adjusted Bond Index (the “Index”).